Listview inside scrollview in swiftui
In Swiftui, I have a list view inside a scrollview. I would like to turn off scrollview scroll. However, Listview ought to scroll. However, it does not function when I use.disabled(true). How would one go about doing this? Someone please help.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var birds = ["Hen","Peacock", "Humming Bird", "Eagle", "Kite", "Vulture"]
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                Text("Birds List")
                List {
                    ForEach(birds, id: \.self) { bird in
                        
                        Text("\(bird)")
                    }
                }.frame(width: geometry.size.width - 5, height: geometry.size.height - 50, alignment: .center)
            }
            .disabled(true)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Scrollview should not scroll but tableview should scroll

Why are you using a ScrollView with List? And what's the point of using a ScrollView if it can't scroll?

Already in a live project it is implemented. Now the requirement is like this

It's actually .scrollDisabled(true). When you use .disabled(true), you mean that users cannot interact with this view, since List was nested inside ScrollView, so both views were disable. Try this:
ScrollView {

}
.scrollDisabled(true) //<- here

Update: If you're supporting lower iOS version, my suggestion is using SwiftUI-Introspect to extract ScrollView.

I tried this but it is after Ios16 only

Updated answer, This library is really helpful in case you want to fall back to UIKit style.
